# How to change the color of axis labels in ManimCommunity/manim's ComplexPlane?

Tags: python, plot, axis, manim

I would like to have a "light theme" for my plots to be "PDF-friendly" in manim v.0.18.0. Thus, the background should be white and the plot itself with the labels should be black. I am able to achieve most of this using the following code.

```py
from manim import *

class WhiteThemeExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        self.camera.background_color = WHITE
        point = -3 + 4j
        plane = ComplexPlane(x_range=(-4, 4, 1), y_range=(-1, 5, 1), axis_config={"color": BLACK})
        self.add(plane)
        dot = Dot(plane.n2p(point), color=ORANGE)
        label = MathTex("-3+4i", color=BLACK).next_to(dot, UR, 0.1)
        self.add(dot, label)
        plane.add_coordinates()
        origin = Dot(plane.n2p(0 + 0j), color=BLACK)
        line = Line(origin, dot, color=BLACK)
        self.add(origin, line)
```

This is run using

```
manim render -pqh -s .\plot.py WhiteThemeExample
```

The result is this: the axis labels are still white.

Manim complex plane plot with white labels:

[image: Manim complex plane plot with white labels]

How can I change these labels to be black?

I've tried passing `color`, `fill_color`, `stroke_color` to `axis_config`, `x_axis_config`, and `decimal_number_config` to `ComplexPlane`'s constructor but no luck (or maybe I'm doing it wrong).

Comment: Just from looking into the documentation, sth. like this should work: Replace `plane.add_coordinates()` with `labels = plane.get_coordinate_labels().set_color(BLACK)`. I think you need to add the labels then too, so add the line `self.add(labels)` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer was provided by @CodingWithMagga :

```py
class WhiteThemeExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        self.camera.background_color = WHITE
        point = -3 + 4j
        plane = ComplexPlane(x_range=(-4, 4, 1), y_range=(-1, 5, 1), axis_config={"color": BLACK})
        self.add(plane)
        dot = Dot(plane.n2p(point), color=ORANGE)
        label = MathTex("-3+4i", color=BLACK).next_to(dot, UR, 0.1)
        self.add(dot, label)

        # these two lines are the answer
        labels = plane.get_coordinate_labels().set_color(BLACK)
        self.add(labels)

        origin = Dot(plane.n2p(0 + 0j), color=BLACK)
        line = Line(origin, dot, color=BLACK)
        self.add(origin, line)
```

[Resulting figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuT4p.png)